# Apache Not Loading Websites and Not loading Locally

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, ubuntu-18.04, apache2.4

Apache2 service able to restart, no error.
Apache stops loading web page after restarting the server (Azure VM)

Status as below:

```
systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-11-13 14:36:18 IST; 2min 27s ago
  Process: 869255 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 487777 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 869260 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 869280 (apache2)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 19193)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─869280 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─869287 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─869288 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─869289 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─869290 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─869291 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Nov 13 14:36:17 nagios3-active systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 13 14:36:18 nagios3-active systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Web Page Error while browsing:
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Error logs:

[Sun Nov 13 13:19:37.431191 2022] [core:notice] [pid 191629] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 13 13:25:19.472411 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 191629] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 13 13:25:19.613453 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 235744] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 13 13:25:19.613515 2022] [core:notice] [pid 235744] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 13 13:44:17.190859 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 235744] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 13 13:44:17.297688 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 404885] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 13 13:44:17.297743 2022] [core:notice] [pid 404885] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 13 13:49:05.478423 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 404885] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 13 13:49:05.633070 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 447609] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 13 13:49:05.633131 2022] [core:notice] [pid 447609] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 13 13:49:32.645430 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 447609] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 13 13:49:32.746787 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 451712] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 13 13:49:32.746853 2022] [core:notice] [pid 451712] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 13 13:53:42.128582 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 451712] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun Nov 13 13:53:42.186683 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 451712] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 13 13:53:42.186701 2022] [core:notice] [pid 451712] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 13 14:30:09.805370 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 451712] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 13 14:30:09.910778 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 813958] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 13 14:30:09.910842 2022] [core:notice] [pid 813958] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 13 14:36:17.959872 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 813958] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 13 14:36:18.084923 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 869280] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 13 14:36:18.084985 2022] [core:notice] [pid 869280] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Tried Restarting the Apache2 services.